# Org-mode, linking between headings topic

Tags: org-mode, spacemacs

- I use Org-mode to manage a knowledge-base system.
- I want to apply the dependency/requirement concept for learning any specific topic:
- Let's say We have 4 nodes, each one represent a "Topic to learn" and have its's own headline entry:

  ```
   (A)
    |
   (B)
    |
    /\
   /  \
  (C)  (D)
  ```
- Learning (A), requires learning (B)
- Learning (B) , requires learning (C) and (D)
- How to imply this concept of "requirement" in org-mode?
- The implication must satisfy a request of showing the hierarchical requirement of any node, Example:

  - requirement(A)= B->(C),(D)
  - requirement(B)= (C),(D)

**What I have tried:**
Using headings to represent the different topics and subheadings to represent the sub-topics:

```
* Topic A
** Topic B
*** Topic D
*** Topic E
```

Can not work because (D) can belong to another subheading other than (A) as a parent.

I am still new to org-mode and emacs so maybe there is a package that can somehow apply the needed approach.
I don't know how to code with Elisp, but if a solution involves coding in Elisp and the code is maybe too long, I would appreciate any sort of hint or guidance on where to start.

Comment: Hi @cuore RT and welcome. Could you give us a simple use case ? I don't understand what you want to do or why. What are the rules you're trying to set up? Also, if you want to set up a knowledge base, there are some packages that can facilitate that. The two most popular are [org-roam](https://www.orgroam.com/) and [denote](https://protesilaos.com/emacs/denote). Personally I use denote.

Comment: Check out org-edna

Comment: In the example you provided, a space is missing between the last `*` and `Topic` for topics B, D & E.

Comment: You might want to look into `org-depend.el`. It is available in the `org-contrib` package from the [ELPA Non-GNU](https://elpa.nongnu.org/nongnu/) repository. The Org mode documentation says: `If you need more complex dependency structures, for example dependencies between entries in different trees or files, check out the module ‘org-depend.el’ in the ‘org-contrib’ repository.`

Answer (score 0):

In org-mode, you can create links with `C-c C-l` (`org-insert-link`).

With these links you can link many things (files, web addresses, etc.). Do `C-h k C-c C-l` or `C-h o org-insert-link RET` to know more about this command.

If you do `C-c C-l Topic E RET Topic B RET`, it will create the following link : `[[Topic E][Topic B]]` (where the first bracket is the address of the link, and the second is the name of the link).

So when you will click on `Topic B` headline, the pointer will go to `Topic E` headline.

I don't understand what you mean by "implying the concept of requirement between org-mode headlines".